# Loop do until fails after exception

Tags: networking, active-directory, powershell, scripting, dhcp-server

```
do

{

Try{
if (New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient -ArgumentList $server,3389 )  
{ 

Write-Host $server 'Ready for RDP connection'-ForegroundColor Green }
}
catch { write-warning $error[0] }
}until ($? -eq $true)
```

Above script block exit after exception can someone help how to continue until it gets *true*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[About Automatic Variables](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables):

> ### $?
>
> Contains the execution status of the last operation. It contains
>   **True** if the last operation succeeded and **False** if it failed.

In your code, the **last operation is (*successful*) `Write-Warning $error[0]`**.

I'd use `Do { … } While ($true)` with [`break` statement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_break) after `Write-Host $server 'Ready for RDP connection -ForegroundColor Green'`

If you insist upon `Until` keyword then rewrite the code snippet as follows:

```
do {
  $LastSuccess = $true
  Try {
    if (New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient -ArgumentList $server,3389 )  
    {
       Write-Host $server 'Ready for RDP connection'-ForegroundColor Green
       ### here's a possible place for (facultative) break
    }
  }
  catch { 
    write-warning $error[0]
    $LastSuccess = $false
  }
} until ( $LastSuccess )
```

In any case, I'd store the `New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient` to a variable. This constructor will automatically **attempt a connection** if supplied the host name and port number of the remote host, and it's the case (`-ArgumentList $server,3389`). Then I'd suppose that a connection is **established** and should be closed (and its resources should be released) later in the script using [`Close()` and/or `Dispose()` and/or `Finalize()` method(s)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient?view=netframework-4.8#methods).

BTW, the `if` inside `try` block is definitely superfluous…